# I can't count how many times same chars used in file

Tags: ruby

I have some text to check for the same chars. When I check:
puts file.count("AB"). The result: 399 but it should be 3

```
alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
  "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T",
  "U","V","W","X","Y","Z"," ",".",",",";",
  "-","'"
]

file = File.read("vt_00.txt")
i = 0


while i < alphabet.count do
  single_char_count = file.count(alphabet[i])
  puts "#{alphabet[i]} = #{single_char_count}"
  j = 0
  while j < alphabet.count do
    two_chars = alphabet[i] + alphabet[j]  
    two_chars_count = file.count(two_chars)
    puts "#{two_chars} = #{two_chars_count}"
    j += 1
  end
  i += 1
end
```

When I check:
puts file.count("AB"). The result: 399 but it should be 3

Comment: Does `'aa'` appear twice or three times in `'aaaa'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-count) works another way.

It counts how many times the characters from the parameter occur in the original string.

For example:

```
"aaaa aaab".count("ab")
# => 8
```

What you need is [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan).

```
"aaaa aaab".scan("ab").count
# => 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe your specific questions have been answered. I would like to suggest an efficient way to obtain the desired substring count.

It's not necessary to extract the substrings into a temporary array and then return the size of the array:

```
"aaba aaab".gsub("ab").count { true }
  #=> 2
```

This employs the underutilized form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) that is called with an argument and no block, in which case it returns an enumerator (that has  nothing to do with string replacements). Think of it as the method `String#each_match`.

[Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) then counts every match for which the value of the block is truthy. I have the block always returning `true` but `"My dog has fleas."` would work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count how many times you have a certain pattern in your file you may try something like this.

```
2.6.3 :008 > "ab aaa ba ab".scan(/ab/).size
 => 2
2.6.3 :009 > "ab aaa ba ab".scan("ab").size
 => 2
2.6.3 :010 > "ab aaa ba ab".split("ab").size
 => 2
```

It's not optimal in cpu if you have a massive file, but will work in your case I guess.

Comment: I think the proper ngram counts are done using a sliding window. So using “split” as you suggest will underestimate self overlapping ngrams such as how many AA occur in BAAABAAAA.

Comment: i don't suggest to use "count"

Comment: I meant split, sorry